# How to initialize record with option types in fsharp

Tags: f#, initialization, option-type, mutable

do you know how I can initialize the variable **ret** below ?

```
   type ReferenceDataResponse = 
      { ResponseError : ResponseError option
        SecurityDatas : SecurityData array option }


   let ToReferenceDataResponse(elem:Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element) =
      let ret =  { ResponseError = null ; SecurityDatas = null }

      if elem.HasElement("ResponseError") then
         ...
      end
```

ps : I imagine I have somehow to declare my record values mutable

**UPDATE :**

As mentioned in the comment, I had a previous usage of None before in my code :

```
 type ZeroOrMany<'a> = 
     | Many of 'a array 
     | None
```

That created a new definition for the symbol 'None' which was hiding the "Option.None" I was trying to refer to here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `None` instead of `null`.

As for updating fields, you can mark them `mutable` or use copy-and-update expressions: `let newRet = { ret with ResponseError = Some(error) }`. Which one you use depends on if you need persistence.

Comment: AH ! I tried that and it was not working : I had used the class None in one of my definition :   type ZeroOrMany<'a> =
      | Many of 'a array
      | None

Comment: Ah, yes. More recent definitions of `None` will hide previous ones.

Comment: If you have ambiguity like that, you can be specific by using `Option.None`, or if necessary for some reason, `Option<ResponseError>.None`.

Answer (score 5):

To create an empty record, you can use `None`:

```
let ret =  { ResponseError = None; SecurityDatas = None }
```

I don't think you want to declare the record as mutable. Instead, you'll probably want to create a clone that contains a new value for some field (i.e. the `ResponseCode`). For example, if you have a function that parses the `ResponseError`, you would write something like:

```
// Start with an empty record that does not contain anything
let ret =  { ResponseError = None; SecurityDatas = None } 

// Add ResponseError if it is defined
let ret1 = 
  if elem.HasElement("ResponseError") then 
     let responseErr = ParseResponseError (elem.GetElement("ResponseError"))
     // Return a new value, with ResponseError set
     { ret with ResponseError = Some(responseErr) }
  else
     // Response error was not set, so we just return the original
     ret
```

If you actually need mutable records, then you can mark the field as `mutable`, but that's not used very often - if you're learning functional programming, then try to keep things imutable - this way, you'll learn how to think about problems differently.
    // Do something more here - maybe return the final result
    ret1

Answer (score 0):

A minor variation on the two existing answers could be:

```
let ToReferenceDataResponse(elem:Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element) =

  if elem.HasElement("ResponseError") then
      let responseErr = ParseResponseError (elem.GetElement("ResponseError"))
      { ResponseError = responseErr ; SecurityDatas = None }
  else
      { ResponseError = None ; SecurityDatas = None }
```

Comment: This won't compile as you set `SecurityDatas=null` which is not allowed